# Creating contextual menus and breadcrumbs in Vue - Is my thinking correct?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I am really struggling with what I think should be a simple idea: Creating a contextual menu or breadcrumb trail based on the page a user is on... (Vue/ Nuxt project)

My application has only a handful pages like /events/_id, /interactions/_id, and so on.

To me, it seems you would want to have some data set into each of these **child** .vue pages that contain the contextual menu or breadcrumb trail as a simple object (Text, icon, link), then pass these back to the parent to render them in the appropriate point on the layout.

I have seen 2 possible approaches when thinking about it this way:

1) Emit an event to the parent layout on page render through a method that passes this data upwards to the parent (Seems to be an uncommon approach. In reality I cannot get this to work either!)

2) Use Vuex to pass the data to the store through a mutation and then pick it up through the parent (This seems needlessly complex to me as we are writing to the Vuex store only to later pick it up in the parent again when there must be a way of just passing the object containing the navigation directly!!!)

I must be thinking about this in totally the wrong way, but I cannot, for the life of me, figure out another approach that makes sense! (Building a load of if or case- type logic into my menus and breadcrumb components to look at the page the user is on seems crazy too). Keeping it all at the child level seems sensible to me.

Can someone please point me in the right direction? as I am struggling with this and have spent hours trying to figure this out. The Vuex method seems like the cleanest but quite expensive on the amount of reads/ writes going on..?

Thanks

Comment: I think you'll want to use Vuex. Set page context from the page component and then use that in your breadcrumb component (which is in your layout)

Comment: Thanks. Thinking about it more, it seems like the logical (If code- heavy!) way indeed :)

Comment: I agree, I find that I'm writing a lot of vuex code for what are essentially CRUD operations. The main tradeoffs for me are you can define _what_ operations can be done and you can get a complete history of your app's state